# "T" character added to serialized date with Django wadofstuff serializer

Tags: django, date, serialization

I recently upgraded to Django 1.4 from 1.1. I have been running WadofStuff Django Serializers 1.0.0. After upgrade, I noticed that dates from my django model get serialized with a 'T' character inserted:

```
{"pk": 7, "model": "ao.message", "fields": {"content_file": "bar.wav", "date": "2012-07-04T10:58:46", "summary_file": "foo.wav"}}
```

What's up with that 'T'? Can/should it be removed? Is there a way to specify my desired output date format to the serializer (say, if I didn't want it to return with a 'T')?

Thanks

Comment: That "T" separates the date from the time in an ISO 8601 date and time. http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=40874

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single point in time can be represented by concatenating: a complete date expression, the letter **T** as a delimiter, and a valid time expression. For example "2007-04-05T14:30" ([Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) )

For further details regarding this **T** insertion in datetime format as far as python is concerned, you may go to this link: "[Python Datetime Representations](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/pdate)". The first example specifically illustrates your problem and suggests its solutions too.